# DataBinding for an arbitrary Model object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

I have an enum (e.g. `Status`) which contains list of status codes and i want to display the meaningful string of these status on the page (bind `Status` to a string).

I also have the `Project` object which has `Status` reference and i successfully using a `CustomPropertyEditor` to bind `Status` to a `String` when `Project` is a command object on the form.

But how can i bind `Status` to a meaningful `String` when i want to display a list of `Project`s on the page that not belong to any form?

The below code always uses default enum string when displaying `Status` objects:

```
<c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project" varStatus="row">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${project.status}" />
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to use spring's MessageSource

```
<c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project" varStatus="row">
    <tr>
        <td><spring:message code="status.code.${project.status}" />
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Then you need to have to corresponding keys in a messages_en.properties (or other language files) :

```
status.code.Foo=The status is foo
status.code.Bar=The status is bar
```

Foo and Bar beeing in your Enum.

Comment: This is absolutely how I would do it.  For me, an enumeration is part of the domain model of an application and must therefore never be tied to UI-specific aspects such as locale-awareness.  You have demonstrated the correct way of getting to a locale-specific representation of an enumeration from its value.  This way, different application concerns have been kept separate, making the application more manageable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have declared `Status` as `public enum Status`, `<c:out value="${project.status}" />` calls `Status.toString()`.  Assuming further that you have not overridden the method `toString` in the `Status` enum, the default implementation from `java.lang.Enum.toString()` is used (`java.lang.Enum` being the base class for all enumerations).  `java.lang.Enum.toString()` simply returns `Enum.name`.

You can either override the `toString()` method in your `Status` enum, returning a value that is more meaningful to the users, or you could call any method on your enum class in your presentation layer.  For example, if you have the method `Status.getTitle()`, you can use it as `<c:out value="${project.status.title}" />`.

Comment: Actually i want to support multilingual so if i do it your way, i have to change domain object (implement `MessageSourceAware` for example), something i would not prefer. Why we can't reuse `CustomPropertyEditor` in this case?

Comment: By the way, i added list of projects in the `Model` in the controller method but in `@InitBinder` method i can't not find them in `WebRequest`? As far as i know, all model attributes will be embedded in web request? Correct if i was wrong